# Samsung 960 EVO M.2 on Windows 10 performance issues

Tags: ssd, performance

I frequently notice that my SSD doesn't seem to perform up to par. I have specifically observed that under Ubuntu 17 it only achieves some 100 MB/s and also under Windows 10 it frequently pegs at 100% while transferring some 20 - 40 MB/s. I'm using Windows more, but I'd say both systems exhibit similar problems while disk benchmarks never seem to suffer from them and fly like rockets. Both systems report the disk as SSD.

However, today something really stupid happened:
I started downloading latest ubuntu image with torrent. Disk immediately got pegged at 100% even though my download bandwidth is only 20 mbit/s. For some reason total disk transfer was reaching some 20 MB/s (10 times the bandwidth). Restarting Windows didn't help.

I should note that system was very responsive during the whole episode, but utorrent (2.2.1) never got to really downloading because disk was so busy. Best I got was some 5 - 7 KB/s.

Resource monitor showed nothing unusual: just the ubuntu image being seriously worked on. Task manager showed total transfer around 20MB/s with average response time varying between 1000 and 2000 ms. uTorrent reported disk being busy at 100% which I have never seen before!

Then just for the heck of it, I ran ATTO disk benchmark. As always, it went to 2,7 GB/s transfer with larger sector sizes.

When ATTO was done, disk usage fell to 1% while writing some 2MB/s and torrent was downloading normally (what it should be doing from the start).

I've looked around the net for a possible solution, but most of the posts about this drive's speed were along the lines: "my SSD only gets me 1800 MB/s, but it should do 3700...". I'd be perfectly happy with 1000MB/s, but I'm not with 30 MB/s. This is what my VERY OLD platter drives can do. Not latest state-of-the-art SSD. Also, my today's experience suggests something else at play.

Any ideas on what is messing with my disk?

Comment: Is disk's firmware up to date?

Comment: Magician says it is

Comment: have you installed the NVMe driver from Samsung?

Comment: I have. Would Magician even work without it?

Comment: Could it be self-limiting speed due to excessive heat?

Comment: No. No indication about that neither from SMART nor from my subjective estimations. The computer is not overheated in any meaning of the word or any section when such slowdowns happen.